# Help translating a Chinese character

Tags: translation, character-identification, simplified-characters

So I came across this character and I have no idea what it means. I've tried looking it up in an online chinese dictionary but was unable to find anything. Does anyone know what this character is and what it means in English? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Chinese character is 愣 (lèng). *Usually* characters with the 心-radical (on the left) are related to emotions.

From Oxford Dictionaries:

adjective

1. distracted
2. blank

verb

1. stare blankly
2. look distracted

Common collocations include 愣住 (～住 roughly means 'to a halt') and 發[发]愣 (發～ suggests initiation; see **發**瘋 'to *go* mad'). Sometimes 愣乎乎, but this is more colloquial than the rest. A synonym of 愣 is 呆; you may say 發呆 as well, occasionally 呆住.

Examples:

- 他原地愣住了 'He stood still, flabbergasted'
- 別老站那兒發愣了 'Don't just stand there staring blankly (at nothing)'